# Integral in math messes up copy-and-paste of text

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, copy-paste

For a document like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\input glyphtounicode.tex
\input glyphtounicode-cmr.tex
\pdfgentounicode=1

\pagestyle{empty} % for quick CTRL+A
\begin{document}
  Some text and then $x$.

  Some text and then $\int_0^1 x$.
\end{document}
```

Trying to copy-paste yields

```
Some text and then x.
Some text and then ∫ 1
0
x.
```

Now, I guess the interval isn’t really properly expressible in plain text (unless it can be done through some funky Unicode composition), but I would not expect the result to be *that* bad – maybe `∫0 1 x`? Is there something I can do for better results?

Comment: [`accsupp`](https://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp)

Comment: The answer linked to defines a new command, which then has to be used for every equation. How would I patch all math (and allow for possible loading of e.g. `amsmath`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    Some text and then $x$.

    Some text and then $∫_0^1 x$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although the answer referred to in the “duplicate of question” might be interesting in the long term, this does exactly what I was looking for in the short term.

Comment: Actually, fractions now seem to be out of order: `$\int x\sin ax\;\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sin ax}{a^2}-\frac{x\cos ax}{a}+C$` when copied gives `∫ x sin ax dx = sin ax  − x cos ax + C a2 a` but I guess `sin ax / a2 - x cos ax / a + C` would be too much to expect